# Python - scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to python and i am trying to do some web scraping on a website to extract the history of numbers selected in a lucky draw.

The website is:https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/

The game is called "Lucky 7".

I am wanting to extract a history of the numbers drawn to see if i can do a probability analysis.
The result history should go back up to 1 week as a draw is done every 4 minutes.
If i could get the colour extracted of the number as well that would also be awesome but the main aim is to get the history of the numbers drawm.

I would like the results to be shown in a excel/csv spreadsheet with the date and time in column a and the numbers running in columns B onwards.

The excel should also automatically update each time i open it to show the latest draw results.

Please see my code below - would really appreciate any assistance.

I am using visual code to do the coding in.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = None
        self.soup = None
        self.samples = None
        self.lastSample = None
        self.numbers = None
    def download(self):
        result = requests.get("https://www.bet.co.za/bet-games/")
        if result.status_code == 200:
            self.content = result.content
        else:
            raise Exception("Download: Could not fetch data.")
    def findSoupSamples(self):
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.content, "html.parser")
        self.samples = self.soup.find('div', {'class': 'game-result'})
    def getLastSample(self):
        allSamples = self.samples.findAll('div', {'class': 'flex'})
        lastSample = None
        for lotterySample in allSamples:
            lotterySample = lotterySample.find('div', {'class': 'game-result'})
            if lotterySample is None:
                break
            lastSample = lotterySample
        self.lastSample = lastSample.parent
    def extractDataFromSample(self):
        resultList = []
        dayTimeString = self.lastSample.find('last-results-item-time').text
        numbers = self.lastSample.findAll('div', {'class': 'game-result'})
        for number in numbers:
            resultList.append(number.text.strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        self.numbers = (dayTimeString, resultList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use their API on URL `https://sbtech.betgames.tv/web/v2/games/results/sbtech_bet_co_za/en/0/{date}/1/{page}/` to get the results:

```
import csv
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


url = 'https://sbtech.betgames.tv/web/v2/games/results/sbtech_bet_co_za/en/0/{date}/1/{page}/'

all_data = []
n = datetime.now()
for i in range(0, 7):      # <-- specify number of days you want to get history from now
    d = (n - timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    p = 1
    while True:
        print('Getting page {} for date {}'.format(p, d))
        data = requests.get(url.format(date=d, page=p)).json()
        for r in data['items']['results']:
            all_data.append([r['run_time'], *['{} {}'.format(i['number'], i['color']) for i in r['results']]])
        if '00:00:00' in data['items']['results'][-1]['run_time']:
            break
        p += 1

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Prints:

```
Getting page 1 for date 2020-06-21
Getting page 2 for date 2020-06-21
Getting page 3 for date 2020-06-21
Getting page 4 for date 2020-06-21
Getting page 5 for date 2020-06-21

...etc.
```

And produces `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]